# Image Manipulation/Map

Tags: ios

I am trying to use load an offline world map for my iOS app. However, I only need to maximum zoom level to be around the size of texas. (I want it so that the maximum zoom covers the entire state of texas on an iphone screen. That is the kind of dimensions I am going for). I am hesitant to use TileMill for this kind of low res map. Is there a way I could use a large image of a world map without uploading an entire map? I need to add pins(btw).

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

If your world map will be zoomable, the most flexible approach is to tile it, even if you think it's overkill now.

If you ever want to change the min/max zoom in the future, it would be much simpler and faster to adjust that, than to have to add tiling in the future because your current image resolution wasn't high enough.

Plus, tiling is far more memory-efficient than trying to load a single large high-res image of your world map.